# Move short description below page product detail title via XML

Tags: magento2, xml

I want to move the short description below the title.

See this screenshot:
[image]

I tried it with XML in `catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
 <move element="product.info.extrahint" destination="page.main.title" />
```

But it doesn't work. Duh! How can I find out the correct names of those blocks? I've looked in the Core `catalog_product_view.xml` and copied the name from it, but it simply doesn't do what I want it to do. Why and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `<move element="product.info.overview" destination="page.main.title" />` worked like a charm.